# Why Android Studio creates two xml layout files

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

The eClipse only creates one acitivity_main.xml file, but Android studio creates two xml layout files. The default layout for acitivity_main.xml is the CoordinatorLayout but for content_main.xml is RelativeLayout.

Why need two xmls ? The default is to refer activity_main as: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main), but I find setContentView(R.layout.content_main) also works.

What is the relationship between these two layouts ?

Is there any difference If I drop a button view to the content_main.xml or I drop a button view to activity_main.xml ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Why create 2 files :

These 2 files are created to make your work **EASIER**. As main file contain your stuff like `FAB, toolbar` in Coordinate layout. Now your content file is file in which you can make UI of view without interrupting the basic flow. I personally recommend this.

> Why need two xmls ? The default is to refer activity_main as:
>   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main), but I find
>   setContentView(R.layout.content_main) also works.

These will work as after all these are layout files so can set as content view.

> Is there any difference If I drop a button view to the content_main.xml or I drop a button view to activity_main.xml ?

No difference at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you tell me how these two xml files related. since the activity_main contains the content_main           When you drop a button to activity_main, is the button goes to content_main ?