# Android Studio activity template

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Whenever i create a new activity from the `Android Studio` template, it creates two XML layout files: activity XML layout that includes other content XML layout. Is there any benefit to doing that? I only found that my layout folder going to grow twice because of that.

Comment: [May be you can find answers from this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35564962/11133724)

Comment: Thanks! I think it is no use to keep 2 of them.

Comment: No need of 2 layout files. keep only one and delete rest of all @Rendy

Comment: But why it creates two files? Usually it is just one

Comment: It is like that by default in Android Studio 3.5 @AndroidAnton